# Spring Kafka consumer removed from consumer group when topic idle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

**Versions**
Spring Boot 1.5.x,
Spring Boot 2.4.x,
Apache Kafka 0.10.2

**The Situation**

We have two service instances hosted on different servers.  Each instance initializes multiple Kafka consumers.  All consumers are listening to the same topic and are part of the same consumer group.
We are **not** relying on Spring Boot/Spring Kafka to configure the ConcurrentKafkaListnerContainerFactory and its DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.  All the consumer configuration properties are set to the default Apache Kafka consumer property values except for max.poll.records, session.timeout.ms, and heartbeat.interval.ms.  Acknowledgement mode is set to record.

We are using the @KafkaListener annotation and setting its containerFactory property with the bean name of the initialized ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and setting it topics property.

**The Problem**

When a topic does not get any messages published to it for a day or two, all consumers are removed from the consumer group.
I can’t find any reason for this to happen.  From my understanding of reading both the Apache Kafka and Spring Kafka documentation if poll is called within max.poll.interval.ms, the consumer is considered alive.  And if heartbeats are continuously sent by the consumer within the session.timeout.ms, the consumer is considered alive.  According to the documentation, poll is called continuously and heartbeats are sent at the interval set by heartbeat.interval.ms.

**The Questions**

1. Is there a setting or property Spring Boot/Spring Kafka is setting that causes a consumer that hasn’t consumed any records from an idle topic for a day or two to be removed from the consumer group?
2. If yes, can this be turned off and what are the downsides?
3. If no, is there a way to rejoin the consumer group without having to restart the service and what are the downsides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Kafka version is very, very old.

Older versions removed the consumer offsets after no activity for 24 hours, even if the consumer is still connected. In 2.0, this was increased to 7 days. With newer brokers (since 2.1), consumer offsets are only removed if the consumers are not actually connected for 7 days.

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_200_notable

You can increase the broker's `offsets.retention.minutes` with older brokers.

Comment: When you say `if the consumers are not actually connected `, I'm wondering what constitutes as `being connected` ? Is it basing on consumer (one that is either subscribed or assigned) background thread heartbeat pings or the consumers actual commits on specific topic/partition combination ?

Comment: Before 2.1; even idle consumers had their offsets expired; now, as long as at least one group member tries to consume within the retention, the offsets won't be expired; read the description of the property: `>After a consumer group loses all its consumers (i.e. becomes empty) its offsets will be kept for this retention period before getting discarded. For standalone consumers (using manual assignment), offsets will be expired after the time of last commit plus this retention period.` When using manual assignment, it's more like the pre 2.1 behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gary. I've gone through the documentation, parts that are not clear - `standalone consumers` and `manual assignment`. What criteria qualifies a consumer being a `standalone consumer` ? What is `manual assignment` - are you referring to `consumer.assign(topic-partitions)`... will the behavior differ when consumers are started using `subscribe` ? FYI all our consumers are configured with `enable.auto.commit` being False.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term standalone here; it it appears to mean consumers that don't use group management (i.e. `assign()` Vs. `subscribe()`). With the former, the clock starts with the last commit; with the latter, the clock starts when the last consumer leaves the group. In Spring, we use `subscribe()` when the container is created with topic names or a topic `Pattern`, we use `assign()` when the container is created with `TopicPartitionOffset`(s).